# how to access a MAMP Pro Site from a different Machine on same Network

Tags: localhost, mamp, server

I',m probably missing something really simple, but I can't access my MAMP Server on a different machine on the same network on default localhost:888.

My sites are stored on the HD of a Mac Mini Server HD and should be accessible.

Can anyone please advise what I need to do to allow access across my network as currently the sites only show on the Mac Mini Server that MAMP is installed on.

Note I'm using default MAM

Thanks
Glennyboy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorted for MAMP ports.

I added a user defined IP in the field "IP Address" in under Hosts (selecting the specific host). So to access my site it is "IPADDRESS:8888" on default MAMP settings.

For default Mac ports this also can work by simply changing the WordPress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL) within Wordpress Settings/General Settings to that of your MAMP/local machines IP address. May require a trailing / + the site directory/mamp site folder.

Comment: What I would also like to know is how to access a Wordpress Multisite across a local network on default Mac ports (as I understand Multisite requires those).